# Problems with R drawable

Tags: java, android

I read other post about R drawable but I still dont understand why i get the error
R is not a resolved variable

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.view.View;
public class TheDrawingSurfaceWindow extends View
{
    public Bitmap imageToBeDrawn;

    public TheDrawingSurfaceWindow(Context context){
        super(context);
        imageToBeDrawn=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.PICTURESTUFF);
    }       
}
```

The `PICTURESTUFF.png` is in the drawable folder but I still get errors plz help

Comment: Please post the stack trace. Without it, there's not a lot that can be done.

Comment: Sorry for not knowing but what is the stack trace

Comment: The stack trace is the list of errors. Basically, select all of the red stuff from the log cat, copy it and paste it in your answer (Click on the edit button)

Comment: R cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/13446065/544198 for an example of how this type of question should be formatted.

Answer (score 3):

Resource names should be in all lowercase. Please rename your file to be `picturestuff.png` and see if that helps.